# RHEL 6 no sound, but volume settings shows 100%

Tags: rhel

My sound worked perfectly on my Thinkpad T430, but ~3 days ago an update (?) came, and from than, the sound icon from the GNOME-panel dissapeared.

I already tried a reboot, no luck.

I tried using "gnome-volume-control", it says it's on 100% volume, but still nothing, no sound in webbrowsers, or from applications.

I checked "alsamixer", It says 150 <> 150 for Master, and not MM.

```
[user@notebook ~]$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 65536 [100%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 65536 [100%] [on]
[user@notebook ~]$
```

**Questions**: how can I resolve this?

Interesting, no package update from ~3 days ago in /var/log/yum.log

UPDATE:

```
yum reinstall pulseaudio
```

didn't helped.

Comment: Have you tried unmuting via the keyboard?  My Thinkpad T420 runs FreeBSD and the keyboard mute seems to work independently to the OS...

Comment: Tried the button, but didn't helped.